# Update on "A Mad day's work" by Cartier

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

In his paper "[A mad day's work: from Grothendieck to Connes and Kontsevich. The evolution of concepts of space and symmetry](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-01-00913-2)," Cartier discusses in the last sections 8 and 9 the role of polyzetas/multiple zeta values in math and physics in summation of divergent series/renormalization in quantum physics.

Is there a recent survey article that contains a good update on these ideas?

Similar ideas were explored in 2014 in the workshop [New Geometric Structures in Scattering Amplitudes](http://www.claymath.org/events/new-geometric-structures-scattering-amplitudes) hosted by CMI with the following partial overview:

> “Recently, remarkable mathematical structures have emerged in the study of scattering amplitudes, revealing deep links to algebraic geometry, arithmetic and combinatorics. There have been many exciting dual representations of amplitudes including

> 1. polytopes, twistor diagrams and the positive grassmannian leading to the concept of the amplituhedron,
> 2. polylogs, multizeta values and multiloop integrals,
>    ...

> Each of these disparate ideas and methods have their own remarkable successes, and indeed have led to important progress in related areas of mathematics. They also face obstacles that they need to overcome in order to become important tools in resolving the most important open conjectures in the field and for the explicit construction of amplitudes.”

Comment: This talk from 2016 by Francis Brown: http://www.ihes.fr/%7Ebrown/SMFBrown.pdf discusses some of the topics in Cartier's article. In particular, he explains motivic versions of multiple zeta values, and a motivic version of Cartier's dream in the last slide.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault, thanks. Hope progess has been made since then revived by interest in the amplituhedron and associated constructs.

Comment: The title of the talk by Brown [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391728/update-on-a-mad-days-work-by-cartier#comment999163_391728) by @FrançoisBrunault:  [Periods and cosmic Galois group](http://www.ihes.fr/~brown/SMFBrown.pdf).